# Is it possible to record audio directly from an app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio-recording

I'm developing an app and a nice feature I would like to implement is audio recording for playback later.

Is this possible using phonegap/cordova?

The only examples I have found record directly from the microphone, which is no good.

I've also had a look at the phonegap docs and the "media.startRecord" doesn't provide me with much insight on how it works.

Comment: If not directly from the mic, what exactly do you want? You want to use a mixer?

Comment: I've basically made a drum machine, 4 different buttons, 4 small mp3 files.
And I would like a record button to capture the users input and save that into a mp3 or amr.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but (as far as I'm aware) you won't be able to use the stock MediaRecorder classes and will actually have to write your own to take input from your own system

Comment: Ah I see, that's where I'll fall flat though. 
I was hoping there would be some sort of plugin available

Comment: But if you are generating the sounds, can't you just record the orders and timings, and reproduce them with those parameters later when needed? That would be better in terms of lower space usage, quicker saving, etc. How are you generating the sounds anyway? Are they synthesized or played from an audio file?

Comment: Yes that's probably the best idea! Trouble is I wouldn't know how to to that, is it simple? My fluency with javascript is limited I'm afraid. And my sounds are small mp3 files that reside in the /assets folders.